# Gradle dependency for springdoc-openapi-ui

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, swagger, openapi

I am trying to use springdoc-openapi-ui using gradle dependency.

Maven

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.3</version>
   </dependency>
```

Gradle

```
    plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.1.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'fete.bird'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '14'
compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs += ["--enable-preview"]
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.SR6")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**Error**

```
Could not find org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:.
Required by:
    project :

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

What is the repository for the gradle?

Comment: `mavenCentral()` ?

Comment: I already have that in my gradle file, didn't work

Comment: Try also `jcenter()` or post your `build.gradle` file please

Comment: With jcenter() also not working

Comment: The Spring Boot BOM probably doesn't declare a version number for that dependency. Try specifying it (e.g. `implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.4.3'`)

Comment: @BjørnVester please post the solution as an answer, and please accept the answer. For a community, it's really important to have an answer that's accepted.

Answer (score 6):

Try adding the library with latest version in your project

`implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.4.6")`

Answer (score 1):

implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui' fail with following error Could not find org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui

While following worked

implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.6'